# Split Table Column on a Specific Character

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to split a value on a specific charater, below is my example.

```
DECLARE @HCode varchar(20);
SET @HCode = '10-101-200-12';
```

I want to split `@HCode` and want to get `12`, any Help..

Comment: I want to split it on '-', and get 12, is it possible.. in this case i have 2 digits in end, but it can grow to 3 digits...

Comment: So you want the number after the third `-` right? whatever the length of it? Is it of the same length or not?

Comment: yes exactly after 3rd `-` and the length is not same. its changing.

Comment: u want the last digit right of ur given input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@HCode), 0, PATINDEX('%[-]%', REVERSE(@HCode))))
```

OR

```
select REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@HCode), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@HCode))-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@HCode), 
               1, 
               CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@HCode)) - 1));
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b6e8/1)

Comment: Its working Thanx.. who's answer i should mark.. Both are working.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal It doesn't matter whose you accept, any one of them :)